# Filter to replace edge points by a circle

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, edge-detection

I have the following HW assignment:
Go to the "saw" image. Do edge detection. Now, by convolution,
replace each edge point by a small circle or with a small Gaussian.

Which filter can I use to perform this operation?

Thank you!

```
saw_image = imread('saw.jpg');
I  = rgb2gray(saw_image);
BW = edge(I,'canny');
[row, col] = find (BW);
a = sub2ind(size(I), row, col)';
WindowSize = 9;
newI=imfilter(I(a),fspecial('???',WindowSize));
```

Comment: You can use a gaussian filter; check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html?searchHighlight=fspecial) for a list of pre-defined filters available with `fspecial`

Comment: When I use a gaussian filter my image becomes one straight horizontal line..

Comment: How about using dilation with a circular structur element?http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what is required.
I assume you should do something like:

```
saw_image = randi(255,30,30,3);
I  = rgb2gray(saw_image);
BW = edge(I,'canny');
WindowSize = 3;
newI=imfilter(BW*255,fspecial('gaussian',WindowSize));

result = saw_image;
result(newI>0) = newI(newI>0);
```

This creates an edge image, convolutes this image and replaces all areas int he original image which are detected as edges with the edge values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this isn't what is required. Saw is an actual saw, and the aim of this section, as far as I understand it, is to replace the "teeth" of the saw with circles.

Comment: Hm, the text "replace each edge point by a small circle" sounds otherwise. To detect the teeth, you could look for corner detection.